# How to use Azure IoT C SDK with an embedded Linux device and COM-port connected modem

Tags: buildroot, modem, azure-sdk

Initially we developed an IoT ready medical device that was supposed to handle IoT via a TCP connection to an online server. However, the customer now asked us whether its possible to use the Azure SDKs instead.
Turns out this is far from easy and quite the challenge for us and we struggle even with getting a basic grip on how "Azure" works and how this SDK can be used in our case.
The system is comprised of:

- An embedded Linux Device with buildroot OS, "backend"-application and a Crank Storyboard UI
- Fibocom MA510 modem connected via COM-Port to the linux device (so no driver integration, we solely communciate via AT-commands over serial from our Linux-application with the modem)

All information I could find was that the Fibocom Module is compatible with the Azure SDK, but the "first steps" guide seems to install the SDK directly on the modem itself instead of in the Linux OS.

Can somebody give us hints as to what documentation is relevant for our case and if this is even a feasible approach at all? I have to admit that the Azure IoT SDK is quite challenging and without previous experience seems impossible to use.

We searched Azure and Fibocom documentation but were not able to get a grip on how to even approach this issue.
We know the modem has a command set for MQTT and since the Azure IoT SDK is based on that, the approach could in theory work. However we don't even know how to get started with such a task.

Comment: please share the code .

Comment: @Sampath what do you mean? We do not have any code regarding the Azure IoT SDK as we are not even aware on how to install and use it with our setup.

Comment: @Sampath any idea on how we could proceed?